# jest - mockReturnValue : Promise<boolean>

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am new and I want to mock a function that returns a `Promise<boolean>.`
I did this:

```
service.changeBookingAsync = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(boolean);
```

but I got this error :

> error TS2693: 'boolean' only refers to a type, but is being used as a
>   value here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to mock a Promise you have to use this:

```
jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(value));
```

Answer (score 17):

Agree with @Max answer

Syntactic sugar function will be this way :

```js
jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(value);
```

Answer (score 4):

There is one more way that we can mock a function that returns a Promise.

```
service.changeBookingAsync = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
```

This is equivalent to

```
jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(true);
```

And `mockFn.mockResolvedValue(true)` is a syntactic sugar function for:

```
jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(true));
```

You can read more on [mockResolvedValue()](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue) from the official documentation of Jest.