# How to mock a function that will have then and catch block?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-hooks-testing-library

I using Firebase authentication and I would like to test the function using Jest and react-hooks-testing-library.

I have a function that like this:

```
const loginWithEmailPassword = (email: string, password: string) => {

    const auth = getAuth()

    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            // Signed in 
            const user = userCredential.user;
            // ...
        }).catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
        });

}
```

The `signInWithEmailPassword()` function have a `then()` and `catch()` block.

I have mock the function with this code:

```
const mockSignUp = jest.fn(() => {
    return Promise.resolve({
        user: {
            uid: "fakeuid",
        },
    });
})

jest.mock('firebase/auth', () => ({
    getAuth: () => mockGetAuth,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword: () => mockSignIn,
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword: () => mockSignUp
}))
```

Then I test the function above using `react-hooks-testing-library` which like this:

```
 test('Login with Email and Password', () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useFirebaseAuth())

    const email = 'abc@gmail.com'
    const password = '123456'
  
    // here fired my loginWithEmailPassword above
    act(() => {
        // the problem come from this line
        result.current.loginWithEmailPassword(email, password)
    })
```

Then my test failed with this error:

```
 TypeError: (0 , _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword)(...).then is not a function

      46 |
      47 |         signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    > 48 |             .then((userCredential) => {
```

If I remove the `then` block, the test passed. But if I use called the `then()` for the function it get the error. I check that my mock for `signInWithEmailAndPassword` with return of `Promise.resolve()` should be ok, but it still having the error.

I am new in testing field. Please somebody give some suggestion on this and tell me what is wrong with my test? I have absolutely no idea

I have tried to mock it like this, after looking for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68139396/4332049):

```
const mockSomething = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({
    user: {
        uid: "fakeuid",
    },
}))
```

But still having the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I able to solve the problem by mock a function with will return promise that resolved with `user` like this:

```
jest.mock('firebase/auth', () => {
    return {
        getAuth: () => mockGetAuth,
         
        // since this method from firebase return a promise, here need a promise as well 
        signInWithEmailAndPassword: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
           user: {
               uid: "fakeUid",
            },
          }),
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
             user: {
               uid: "fakeUid",
             },
          }),
    }
})
```

in the `signInWithEmailPassword` , I direct return the `Promise` without wrap it with `jest.fn()`

Then in test, I can do this:

```
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword, getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

// here I can check that `signInWithEmailPassword is call with some value
expect(signInWithEmailAndPassword).toBeCalledWith(
  getAuth(),
  email,
  password
);

// Here I can compare my UI to the fakeUid as well 
expect(data.user.uid).toEqual('fakeUid')
```

In test, I have to call `signInWithEmailAndPassword` which is direct from `firebase/auth`.

Since I already mock the function in `jest.mock()`, therefore in test it will return back the fake data I defined directly, which is `data: { user: { uid: 'fakeUid' } }`

The whole process is like:

- There are an actual function in `firebase/auth` module named `signInWithEmailPassword`
- But I dont want to "really" call that, therefore I make a fake function with same name that will return the same thing(Promise in this case) of the actual function inside `jest.mock()`
- Now, in `test` section, I call the function direct from Firebase, but now instead of "actual" calling it from Firebase, it just return the "fake" `Promise` with the fake data that I defined just now.
- Then I can compare it to a value by using `expect(data.user.uid).toEqual('fakeUid')`